# Element is not at clickable point

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver, web-testing

I had put linktext and its corrects but the error comes like Element ... is not clickable at point (750, 38).

My tried code:

```
driver.get("https://staging.keela.co");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 15);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Log In")));
element.click();

//waiting for  to load
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-email']")).sendKeys("bandana@yopmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-password']")).sendKeys("keela");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed in your code, that after click on `Login in` button, you are not providing any `wait`. so due to this reason, you get an error.

I have try the same below code on my end and it is working fine for me.

Try this below code.

```
driver.get("https://staging.keela.co");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Log In")));
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log In")).click();

new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-email']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-email']")).sendKeys("bandana@yopmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-password']")).sendKeys("keela");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary']")).click();
```

Refer Image

[image]

Comment: @Bandana Singh, Have you try this code? Please Replace your code with mine and let me is it working fine for you or not?

Comment: Are you sure, you replaced my code properly?. Because the same code is working fine for me without showing any error.

Comment: did it allowed you to login and enter dashboard??

Comment: No, it is not allowing me to access the dashboard, just because when i click on `submit` button, I got this error. `User not found`

Comment: So, Here error is not inside my code, might be username or password is getting changed. So try once with valid username and password, using the same code.

Comment: same error ..element is clickable at point something like that

Comment: yaa..I had provide wrong username just to post here so that my real account wont be misused.Actually firstly i need to click that Log in button.

Comment: I guess you are not replacing my code properly dear. after `element.click()` method, have you put this code `new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-email']")));`

Comment: I will show you screenshot as well, Please refer my updated answer. My code is working fine without giving me any error. So make sure, replace your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine in Chrome, I am just increasing the wait time and use  for click:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\software and tools\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://staging.keela.co/");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 50);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Log In")));
        element.click();

        //waiting for  to load
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-email']")).sendKeys("bandana@yopmail.com");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-password']")).sendKeys("keela");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary']")).click();
```

Actually your website take too much time to load so that you have ti nncrease wait time

Comment: Your id and password is wrong, not allowed to login

Comment: oh thank you so much.I have been looking from top to button just to find mistake in my code.but shit how can I forgot about to increase wait time.Anyway thanks for saying.

Comment: @ iamsankalp89, Can you explain me after `element.click()`, how your webdriver will know that you have to wait?

Comment: that comment is written by Questioner, I did not write it

Comment: Yes, but you can coreect it na.

Comment: @iamsankalp89, My answer is also right, however i have provided sufficient time for page loading. and I have provided screenshot as well.

Comment: I know that comment should be before driver wait..its my mistake I forgot to cut over there

Comment: @Bandana Singh, Due to wait not providing after `element.click()`, you will get an error, because your driver may take sometime to loading the page, and if you are not providing any wait, you will get an error like `Element is not clickable` so in my opinion my answer is better than this.

Comment: As from seeing both the answers, I can conclude that @jainish answer is better than this answer. But it does not mean that this answer is not helpful. It is also helpful answer. `wait` should be provided but, suficient amount of `wait` is good practice.

Comment: @JainishKapadia Your answer style is too Good

Comment: @iamsankalp89, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform click action using JavascriptExecutor

```
//Creating the JavascriptExecutor interface object by Type casting      
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;    

WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary']")); 

//waiting for  to load
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-email']")).sendKeys("bandana@yopmail.com");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-password']")).sendKeys("keela");

//Perform Click using JavascriptExecutor        
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```